# how to obtain summary of statistics for distinct values of a column in dataframe in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Consider we have a `data.frame` named `IND`, in which we have a column called `dept`. There are in total 100 rows and there are 20 distinct values in `dept`.

Now I would like to obtain the summary statistics for these 20 subsets of `data.frame` containing 5 rows each using the main `data.frame`!

`summary(IND)` gives the summary statistics for whole dataset but what should I do in my case?

Comment: `by(IND,IND$dept,summary)` ?

Comment: You may also check `?summaryBy` from `library(doBy)`

Comment: Thank you very much scoa.. that gave the required result!

Comment: @akrun it is probably a duplicate, but I don't think this is the right question to point to. The answers over there are only about summarizing *one* variable by groups, whereas the OP wants to summarize *every* variable in the data.frame, by group. The first answer with `tapply` doesn't work here for instance

Comment: @scoa I reopened.  As the OP didn't provide an input example/expected output, it is not that clear.  There was also a `summaryBy` option in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum, mean))
```

can be used for your case as

```
IND %>% group_by(dept) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum, mean))
```